# Substracting two values in Android and display

Tags: java, android, textview

Hi I am developing an android app...in which there is a datepicker to select the date of birth where when the user enters a dateo f birth the month has to be substracted from the year and the value has to be again added till it reach a single digit ... i did some code please check if it correct or no...when I checked it is not working out.. If anyone knows pls help...

```
sum5=getSum4(tv3.getText().toString());

              i.putExtra("name4", sum5 + "");  

date.init(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth(),new OnDateChangedListener()
    {


    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker  arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



     String date=Integer.toString(arg3);
     String month=Integer.toString(arg2);
     String year=Integer.toString(arg1);

     tv3.setText(year + month+1);



    }   

});}

    }


public long getSum4(String text) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long sum5 = 0;
        char[] name4 = new char[text.length()];
        name4 = text.toCharArray();


        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {
            sum5 -= value4( name4[i] );

        }
        while (sum5>9)
        {
            sum5 = findDigitSum(sum5);
        }

        return sum5;
    }


    public long findDigitSum4(long n) 
    {
        int sum5 = 0;
        while (n != 0) 
        {
            sum5 += n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum5;
    }



private int value4(char a) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(a) {
            case '1': 
               return 1;

             case '2':
                return 2;

              case '3':
                 return 3;
              case '4':
                  return 4;
              case '5':
              return 5;
              case '6': 
                   return 6;

                 case '7':
                    return 7;

                  case '8':
                     return 8;
                  case '9':
                      return 9;  
                      default:
                          return 1;

        }


}

}
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: when i enterd the date of birth as 10 Aug 2013 ... the value has to be 2013 - 8(Aug)...that means 2+0+1+3 = 6 - 8 then value must be 2, but i am getting -15 .. but negative shoudn't to be come...

Comment: As a side note, you should probably work on your code style/formatting. It's terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three edittexts and and take the value for year and month seperately. then substract it from the year value ..then use your code to make into a single digit